# Compare stock values with submitted quantity values

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to compare number of items in stock with the submited number in quantity.
If quantity is greather than items in stock an alert should be shown.

This is what I have, and it doesn't seem to work.

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
if($('#instock').val() < $('#quantity').val(){
alert('There are currently not enough items in stock');    
else    
return false;
  }
});
```

And fiddle her: http://jsfiddle.net/pthv/t5LhY/3/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/RsGeC/)</kbd>

```
if ($('#instock').text() < $('#quantity').val()) {
    //            ^need .text() here           ^ missing closing if bracket (
```

---

```
<div id="instock">200</div> // you need .text() to 200 from div
```

[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

.val() is used with form-elements like textbox,select,radio,checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a closing bracket, and some curly brackets around your `else`. You should also make sure you're comparing numbers, as `val` and `text` return a string.

```
if (parseInt($('#instock').text()) < parseInt($('#quantity').val())) {
    alert('There are currently not enough items in stock');   
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Grim.
Thanks for your reply. It works, but when I test in Fiddle it show this error after click on alertbox:
{"error": "Shell form does not validate...

Comment: Anything after the alert box is nothing to do with that little bit of code.